# What is this bulb with pink and white globular flowers?

Tags: identification, bulbs

I had this bulb given to me as "Mayflower" or "Morning Glory". My Internet search leads me to believe that the flower is not either of the above.

It flowers annually in May-June. It has a pink and white flower.

Could someone please identify this flowering bulb?

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like a Scadoxus to me. The [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scadoxus) page may help to confirm.